# Elasticsearch query does not give back id (but all other data)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch, and I've written (to be more precise generated) a simple query to retrieve saved data created by a certain user.

The query gives back right results, my problem is that the `id` and/or the `_id` field is missing from the result. All other fields are retrieved perferctly, the condition is okay too.

Can you suggest me, how to include the ˙id˙ field to the result?
Here is the query:

```
{
  'filter': {
    'limit': {'value': 100}
  }, 
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'should': [
        {'term': {'user': 'acct:test_user@0.0.0.0:5000'}}
      ], 
      'minimum_number_should_match': 1
    }
  }
}
```

(I know I can write the query simpler but it is designed that other terms will be added to it)
The user field's definition is simple too:

```
'user': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'}
```

Thanks for the help. I'm aware that this is may be a rookie question, but I just can't get it right.

Comment: The `id` should always be present in the result. Can you give use the response you get back when running this query ?

Comment: Just to make sure you know, `_id` is not part of the document body like other fields. Unless you duplicate `_id` in the document, you won't see it in the `_source` part of a result.

Comment: You will get `_id` returned, but not "in the same place" as the other fields, that is not in the `_source`.

Comment: @ramseykhalaf has absolutely right, I was checking only the ```_source``` part, the ```_id_``` is one level higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure you know, `_id` is not part of the document body like other fields. Unless you duplicate `_id` in the document, you won't see it in the `_source` part of a result.

You will get `_id` returned, but not "in the same place" as the other fields, that is not in the `_source`, it is one level higher.